# Different names for eGFR measurement

Tags: diabetes, kidney, coloration-discoloration, urine, glomerular-filtration-grf

I had a look at our hospital database and found out that we have the below measurements

Estimated Glomerular Filtration          ml/min
Estimated Glomerular Filtration Rate     ml/min
Estimated Glomerular Filtration, Female  ml/min
Estimated Glomerular Filtration, Male    ml/min

Am I right to understand that terms with `Male` and `Female` are being very specific or the doctor/data entry was made in such a specific manner.

For example, if we look at `Estimated Glomerular Filtration` or `Estimated Glomerular Filtration` they are no different from `Estimated Glomerular Filtration, Male` or `Estimated Glomerular Filtration, Female`

Am I right to understand this? It's just the level of info which was keyed in the EHR system?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you please clarify the core of your question?

Comment: The expected eGFR ma be different for male vs female, and the "normal range" values displayed or printed  next to the subject's measured value may thus be different depending on whether ", Male", ", Female", or neither is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eGFR is calculated differently based on several factors, including sex and race. So there are different calculation formulas based on male vs female, and African American vs Caucasian. There are not currently differences for other ethnicities, but there are some studies working on validating those.

[Source](https://www.kidney.org/sites/default/files/docs/12-10-4004_abe_faqs_aboutgfrrev1b_singleb.pdf)